504 Gateway Timeouts
Our Nginx server with WordPress 6.5.5 and PHP 8.2 is randomly encountering 504 errors, resource spikes and crashing. While using a response time monitor, I have seen long periods of time in the 0ms range and suddenly, this has increased even higher. (Above 700ms) Regarding the following response time data image, is there anything noticeable from this behavior that I'm missing? Is it normal for response times to bounce between 858ms and 1310ms? Any insight is appreciated. (All theme/plugins are up to date and have increased PHP max_execution_time and other theme requirements.) Thank you.


Do you have a proxy server involved?  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/504

I have to assume. Unfortunately, I'm being told, by IT, that it's Wordpress, and specifically WooCommerce. I know, that's not a lot to work with. I guess the miracle I'm searching for, without a whole lot to provide, is that the chart above is irrelevant, or that fluctuating response times are normal (based on traffic/resources ect.). But,I have not been able to correlate the "peaks" in the chart with visitors.

According to Google, a good server response time (SRT) is under 200 milliseconds (ms). A response time of 100 ms or less is ideal, and anything above 500 ms is a problem.
